# I need to write a trigger in oracle before insert statement using 2 tables

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Table 1
**RPA_DUTY_BUDGET**

```
column : material
column : duty_budget
```

Table 2
**RPA_IMPORTS**

```
column : material
column : grn
column : amount
column : duty_actuals
column : duty_budget
```

When I need to **insert the data** into **RPA_IMPORTS** then I need to search for the material and its corresponding duty_budget from **RPA_DUTY_BUDGET** and insert those values.

I could easily achieve this by using a join, however the since the duty changes periodically it will take the latest duty, that is the reason, I need to store in RPA_IMPORTS for further calcualtion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't even require a *join*.

```
create or replace trigger trg_biu_imp
  before insert or update on rpa_imports
  for each row
begin
  select d.duty_budget
    into :new.duty_budget
    from rpa_imports i
    where i.material = :new.material;
end;
/
```

Comment: I am getting an error while trying to insert a record.

Comment: PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.MATERIAL'

Comment: What I meant was that we want to insert into rpa_imports then it needs to get the duty_budget from rpa_duty_buget and then insert into rpa_imports

Comment: That's what this trigger does. Error you got means that there's no column named MATERIAL in table named RPA_IMPORTS. **However**, according to information you posted in question, the very first column *is* MATERIAL. Therefore, either you didn't post what you really have, or there's something else going wrong.